# How to delete multiple values?

Tags: oracle

I have 3 identical values:

```
2814|Venerdì 13  |1980   |Orrore      |1:30    |Dvd      |Italiano
2815|Venerdì 13  |1980   |Orrore      |1:30    |Dvd      |Italiano
2816|Venerdì 13  |1980   |Orrore      |1:30    |Dvd      |Italiano
```

I have tried to delete mutiple with this query

```
delete from titolo where idtitolo > '2814'  and idtitolo < '2815';
```

But this deleted 0 lines.
How delete two values using one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The less than and greater than are not inclusive, there is no number in the list you gave that is more than 2814 AND less than 2815.

Try this instead:

```
DELETE 
FROM titolo 
WHERE idtitolo BETWEEN 2814 AND 2815
```

Answer (score 1):

`idtitolo > '2814'  and idtitolo < '2815'` is an impossible where, because `<` and `>` are "less than" and "greater than" comparisons (open limits) and, as so, don't include the limit values. And there's nothing between 2814 and 2815.

Why should use `<=` (less equal) and `>=` (greater equal) if you want .

Either use

```
delete from titolo where idtitolo >= '2814'  and idtitolo <= '2815';
```

or

```
delete from titolo where idtitolo IN ('2814', '2815');
```

will delete rows with `idtitolo` 2814 and 2815.